# Trigger Teamcity build from bitbucket cloud on pull request

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I have been trying to trigger a build on TC on PR but the refs I have access to TC doesnt include refs/pull or refs/pull-request. Is this a Bitbucket cloud thing? Given that being the case how do I trigger build specifically on pull request?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bitbucket PR plugin for TeamCity: https://github.com/ArcBees/teamcity-plugins/wiki/Configuring-Bitbucket-Pull-Requests-Plugin

Bitbucket doesn't seem to offer access to pull requests the same way github does, but the plugin does the trick for us.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin is not production ready anymore, had a look at it before. Was hoping there would be a cheeky hack for it but haven't found anything yet, so I decided to move to the hosted option for now. Cheers for replying.